# Reading custom Outlook form fields programatically

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I'm investigating possibility to create custom e-mail form with some additional fields that user will need to fill before sending.
I've managed to create such form and display custom fields on read pane of received e-mail  on the same machine in Outlook.

Then I sent this e-mail to gmail to verify if this custom data is there but I don't see it.

Where are those custom fields stored? Maybe it works in Outlook/Exchange only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work only with Outlook running against Exchange server.